# Flicking when I use iTunes on Windows Vista

Tags: windows-vista, 64-bit, itunes, display

I recently bought a Dell Precision with a 23" SP2309W Full HD Widescreen monitor using the default video port on the motherboard and my monitor flickers when I use iTunes to manage my music.

It is running at 1920 by 1080 with a refresh rate of 60 Hhz.  I can not increase the refresh rate.

I am running Windows Vista x64 Home Premuim edition.

Does this happen to anyone else and do they know how to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely a problem with iTunes. I had UI artifacts, the interface jammed up and I had flickering, just as you. This occurs on 64 bit versions of Windows. There's no real solution to this, unfortunately.

Comment: I upgraded to latest version of iTunes (9.0) and it still occurs.

Comment: Unfortunately, like I said, there's no real solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating video drivers and turn hardware acceleration to full

Comment: The video card drivers are up to date and I do not see any option for hardware acceleration.